# Cannot make printf work on STM32H743I_EVAL2

Tags: debugging, stm32

I have been working for quite some time on Nucleo boards. I am used to configure the printf to output on the virtual com port.

However I couldn't make it work on STM32H73I-EVAL2. I know that the setting is different since it uses USART1 to connect to STLink and of course different GPIOs. I checked ST example code and the board user manual to know these differences. I also noticed that some jumpers JP7 and JP8 have to be switched in order to output USART1 signals on STLink instead of physical RS232 connector.

Here are the points I checked:
- GPIOs setting (pins, pullups, speed, etc...)
- USART1 setting (clock enable, clock selection...)
- COM port setting (baudrate, parity, etc...)
- Jumpers on the board
- Putty setting on my PC

I also tried through physical RS232.

Is there any trick or specificity on this board ?

Comment: Have you already tried to talk to the USART peripheral directly, and to send out characters with HAL_UART_Transmit()/HAL_USART_Transmit() (in the case you're using the HAL)? - And, do you see the TX/RX lines move when data is transmitted by the MCU or PC (LEDs blinking on a USART-to-USB adapter board, or checked with a DMM/oscilloscope/logic analyzer)?

Comment: @rel, yes I tried directly with HAL_UART_Transmit. I don't have any scope however I didn't check LED blinking.Will give it a try.

Comment: Ok! If you measure the voltages with a multimeter or even the LEDs, it is possible that you'll not really see much change, because the voltages jump around too fast for only a short amount of time, depending on your baud rate/amount of data. So you could simply make the test buffer larger, and fill it with appropriate data, and lower the baud rate too, to see voltage change more clearly... - If it doesn't change at all, it might have something to do with the initialization of the peripheral, I guess.